# extract the content excerpt from Apache solr

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, indexing

I have used Solr for my Mysql table to index as well as search.Now i want to get an excerpt from the matched results and also high lighten it .
Where Do i have to make changes 
is it here ? if yes , what ?

```
<requestHandler name="/browse" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>

       <!-- VelocityResponseWriter settings -->
       <str name="wt">velocity</str>



       <str name="v.template">browse</str>
       <str name="v.layout">layout</str>
       <str name="title">Solritas</str>

       <str name="defType">edismax</str>
       <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
       <str name="rows">10</str>
       <str name="fl">*,score</str>
       <str name="mlt.qf">
         text^0.5 features^1.0 name^1.2 sku^1.5 id^10.0 manu^1.1 cat^1.4
       </str>
       <str name="mlt.fl">text,features,name,sku,id,manu,cat</str>
       <int name="mlt.count">3</int>

       <str name="qf">
          text^0.5 features^1.0 name^1.2 sku^1.5 id^10.0 manu^1.1 cat^1.4
       </str>

       <str name="facet">on</str>
       <str name="facet.field">cat</str>
       <str name="facet.field">manu_exact</str>
       <str name="facet.query">ipod</str>
       <str name="facet.query">GB</str>
       <str name="facet.mincount">1</str>
       <str name="facet.pivot">cat,inStock</str>
       <str name="facet.range">price</str>
       <int name="f.price.facet.range.start">0</int>
       <int name="f.price.facet.range.end">600</int>
       <int name="f.price.facet.range.gap">50</int>
       <str name="f.price.facet.range.other">after</str>
       <str name="facet.range">manufacturedate_dt</str>
       <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.start">NOW/YEAR-10YEARS</str>
       <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.end">NOW</str>
       <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.gap">+1YEAR</str>
       <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.other">before</str>
       <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.other">after</str>



       <!-- Highlighting defaults -->
       <str name="hl">on</str>
       <str name="hl.fl">text features name</str>
       <str name="f.name.hl.fragsize">0</str>
       <str name="f.name.hl.alternateField">name</str>
     </lst>
     <arr name="last-components">
       <str>spellcheck</str>
     </arr>
     <!--
     <str name="url-scheme">httpx</str>
     -->
  </requestHandler>
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to change the following configurations to enable highlighting and specify the fields on which they need to be enabled.

```
   <!-- Highlighting defaults -->
   <str name="hl">on</str>
   <str name="hl.fl">text features name</str>
   <str name="f.name.hl.fragsize">0</str>
   <str name="f.name.hl.alternateField">name</str>
```

Check [HighlightingParameters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters) which would detail each of the parameters you can configure for highlighting.

Comment: Hey , thanks  . . I have done with Highlightening , i did it in my PHP code , But I am not able to get the excerpt of the content